# Simple correlation question

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Z$ and $Y$ be standard normal and independent random varibales. Define $X := \sqrt{p} Z + \sqrt{1-p} Y$. What is the correlation between X and Z?

My approach:

Corr(X, Z) = $E(XZ) /1 = E(\sqrt{p} Z^2) / 1 = \sqrt{p}$

However, a book I am reading says that the correlation is $p$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your answer is correct by the way.

Comment: The book is wrong, unless you misread something. Perhaps the linear combination was meant to be $X := \sqrt{p^2} Z + \sqrt{1-p^2} Y$?

Comment: Just to concur with the other comments: The usual way to define simple serial correlation in a time series is $X_i=\rho X_{i-1}+\sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z_i$ so $\sqrt{\rho}$ is almost certainly a typo and should simply be $\rho$.